# django hosting with mysql

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I m running my python base REST services on DJango free hosting site called "pythonanywhere".

So far each web service was ~100ms in response thus my frontend was super fast, but last few days response is drastically changed, now for same REST API I am getting 30 seconds.

With above performance I cannot schedule my demo, I am planning to setup new django/python/mysql base environment for myself.

What are the best ways to host/setup Django based application (with mysql), preferably free hosting but I dont mind spending few bucks for better service.

Comment: This is like asking _"I want to buy a car because the one I have now is starting to feel slow. Can you recommend a car? I'm not going to tell you anything about the car I have now"_, in other words it is not a good question. SO is also not a recommendation engine.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here. We had a server misconfiguration that was causing a bottle-neck. We fixed it about 2hrs ago. If you're still having trouble, drop us an email on support or post on the forums and we'll try to work it out.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, but I am still facing same issues - let me follow up on support email.

Answer (score 1):

For production deployment setups [the recommended deployment is with `wsgi`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/).

StackOverflow is not the right place to solicit blanket recommendations especially since you haven't given any idea of what your expected load/usage is.

If you just need something to run your application "online" quickly; a PaaS provider should provide the quickest ramp up time. I have used [heroku](http://heroku.com) before and its very [simple to get started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).

Comment: Hi Burhan, currently I am in prototype mode thus my load would be very less, may be internal to friends and family - are you suggesting  dedicated servers with apache WSGI, mysql setup from scratch ? I might need to register DNS and what not!

Comment: I don't know what to recommend since you haven't given me anything to base recommendations on. If you just need something quick to run your app "online" [heroku](http://heroku.com) is very quick to get started with.